# match dates with different dataframes in r

Tags: r, datetime, dplyr

I have two data frames. the first data frame look like that.

```
user_id   date  
1         2016-12-30
2         2016-08-01
```

the second data frame looks like that

```
user_id    date         total     type 
1          2016-12-19   100       1
1          2016-11-02   200       2
1          2016-10-18   50        1
1          2016-07-15   100       3
1          2016-01-21   200       1
1          2016-01-18   152       2
2          2016-08-01   30        4
2          2016-01-29   133       2
```

I am trying to match the user_id and the date in the two data frames and >> select the last 3 month >> summarize the total

i have tried to group them it works but i still cant compare date with dataframes.

```
library(dplyr)
    df %>%
      group_by(user_id, type_cat) %>% 
      summarise(total= sum(total))

library(lubridate). 
 df %>%
  select (user_id,date, total, type) %>%
  filter(date  >= today() - months(3))
```

The results that i am looking for is :

```
user_id total type
1       150   1  
1       200   2  
1       0     3
1       0     4
2       0     1
2       0     2
2       0     3
2       30    4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df1 = read.table(text = "
user_id   date  
1         2016-12-30
2         2016-08-01
", header=T, stringsAsFactors=F)

df2 = read.table(text = "
user_id    date         total     type 
1          2016-12-19   100       1
1          2016-11-02   200       2
1          2016-10-18   50        1
1          2016-07-15   100       3
1          2016-01-21   200       1
1          2016-01-18   152       2
2          2016-08-01   30        4
2          2016-01-29   133       2
", header=T, stringsAsFactors=F)

library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

# update to date columns (if needed; you probably have date columns already)
df1$date = ymd(df1$date)
df2$date = ymd(df2$date)

df1 %>%
  left_join(df2, by="user_id") %>%           # join datasets
  filter(date.y >= date.x - months(3)) %>%   # keep df2 dates within last 3 months from date in df1
  group_by(user_id, type) %>%                # for each user and type
  summarise(total= sum(total)) %>%           # get totals
  ungroup() %>%                              # forget the grouping
  complete(user_id, type=unique(df2$type))   # add missing combinations
```

Which returns:

```
# # A tibble: 8 x 3
#   user_id  type total
#     <int> <int> <int>
# 1       1     1   150
# 2       1     2   200
# 3       1     3    NA
# 4       1     4    NA
# 5       2     1    NA
# 6       2     2    NA
# 7       2     3    NA
# 8       2     4    30
```

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

This does what you want, though it can't add `user_id`/`type` pairs that don't exist in the data. Most of it is a pretty simple `left_join`, with a few `mutate` steps to convert your `date` values into actual data objects.

The key is at the `summarize` step at the end. We sum up the value of `total` for each group, but before summing, we multiply it by the `logical` test of whether the `date` value is within 3 months of the `key_date`. If `TRUE`, this `=1` and the value is summed, if `FALSE`, then this `=0` and the value is not counted.

We could also use `filter` to remove rows that fail this test, but this way all `user_id`/`type` combinations are preserved, even if `total == 0`:

```
df1 %>%
    mutate(date = ymd(date)) %>%
    rename(key_date = date) %>%
    left_join(df2, by='user_id') %>%
    mutate(date = ymd(date)) %>%
    group_by(user_id, type) %>%
    summarize(total = sum(total * (date > key_date - months(3))))

# A tibble: 5 x 3
# Groups:   user_id [?]
  user_id  type total
    <int> <int> <int>
1       1     1   150
2       1     2   200
3       1     3     0
4       2     2     0
5       2     4    30
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to first join the two dataframes and then use th `group_by` and `summarize` combination. To preserve all type the subsetting regarding the dates has to be done in the `summarize`-call and not in a `filter`-argument (I'll further illustrate what I mean).

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

my_data1 %>% 
  rename(due_date = date) %>% 
  right_join(my_data2, by = "user_id") %>%
  group_by(user_id, type) %>% 
  summarise(total = sum(total[date >= due_date - months(3)]))

# A tibble: 5 x 3
# Groups:   user_id [?]
#   user_id  type total
#     <int> <int> <int>
# 1       1     1   150
# 2       1     2   200
# 3       1     3     0
# 4       2     2     0
# 5       2     4    30
```

I renamed the `date`-column in the first dataframe to make clear that this is the date, where the 3 months are deducted. The `right_join`, ensures that only those `user_id`s with a `due_date` are joint to the data, otherwise you might want to specify what happens with those without date in the first dataframe. 
As mentioned above the subsetting regarding the date range is done in the `summarize`-call, if is done in a `filter`-call before this happens:

```
my_data1 %>% 
  rename(due_date = date) %>% 
  right_join(my_data2, by = "user_id") %>% 
  group_by(user_id, type) %>% 
  filter(date >= due_date - months(3)) %>% 
  summarise(total = sum(total))

# A tibble: 3 x 3
# Groups:   user_id [?]
#   user_id  type total
#     <int> <int> <int>
# 1       1     1   150
# 2       1     2   200
# 3       2     4    30
```

**Data**

```
my_data1 <- 
  structure(list(user_id = 1:2, 
                 date = structure(c(17165, 17014), class = "Date")), 
            class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))

my_data2 <- 
  structure(list(user_id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), 
                 date = structure(c(17154, 17107, 17092, 16997, 16821, 16818, 17014, 16829), class = "Date"), 
                 total = c(100L, 200L, 50L, 100L, 200L, 152L, 30L, 133L), 
                 type = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 2L)), 
           class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I create your data frames.

```
df1 <- read.table(text="user_id   date  
1         2016-12-30
2         2016-08-01", 
                  header = TRUE, 
                  colClasses = c("integer", "POSIXct"))

df2 <- read.table(text = "user_id    date         total     type 
1          2016-12-19   100       1
                  1          2016-11-02   200       2
                  1          2016-10-18   50        1
                  1          2016-07-15   100       3
                  1          2016-01-21   200       1
                  1          2016-01-18   152       2
                  2          2016-08-01   30        4
                  2          2016-01-29   133       2", 
                  header = TRUE,
                  colClasses = c("integer", "POSIXct", "integer", "factor"))
```

Next, I join them together renaming `date` in the first to avoid confusion. Then, I filter to the last three months before `date_ref` (the new name for `date` in the first data frame.) I group by `user_id` and by `type`, calculate the total, fill in the missing `type` values with a `total` of `0` using `complete`.

```
df2 %>% 
  left_join(df1, by ="user_id", suffix = c("", "_ref")) %>% 
  filter(date >= date_ref %m-% months(3)) %>% 
  group_by(user_id, type) %>% 
  summarise(total = sum(total) ) %>% 
  complete(user_id, type = levels(type), fill = list(total = 0))
```

This gives:

```
# # A tibble: 8 x 3
# # Groups:   user_id [2]
# user_id type    total
# <int> <chr>     <dbl>
# 1       1 1       150
# 2       1 2       200
# 3       1 3         0
# 4       1 4         0
# 5       2 1         0
# 6       2 2         0
# 7       2 3         0
# 8       2 4        30
```

Comment: That is nice thing, i like it. Thank you